# How to iterate over single or multiple items?

Tags: python, iterator

For convenience I'd like to pass a function either a single value, a list, or an iterator over multiple values. Ideally there's a way to generate an iterator from a single item so that one loop can accommodate all three variations.

```
def flexible_func(param):
    for x in mystery_wrapper(param):
        do_something(x)

flexible_func('single')
flexible_func(['one', 'two'])
flexible_func(generator)
```

---

Here's what I finally went with:

```
from collections import Iterable

def iterate(seq_or_single):
    if isinstance(seq_or_single, Iterable) and not isinstance(seq_or_single, basestring):
        return seq_or_single
    return [seq_or_single]

# for x in iterate(param):
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if param is a string?

Comment: @gnibbler, hah! good question - for my specific use case I'd like to consider a string as a single parameter. But I'm open to answers that treat it as an iterable sequence of characters.

Comment: I do doubt whether it is a good decision to implement such a function.

Comment: This is asking for problems when you later pass in something you don't realize is going to trigger the iterable behavior, like a file or an exception or something.

Answer (score 3):

```
def flexible_func(param):
    try:
        # If it's any kind of iterable, you can iterate over it
        for x in mystery_wrapper(param):
            do_something(x)
    except TypeError:
        # Not iterable, so it's a single item
        do_something(param)
```

If you're worried about `do_something` throwing a TypeError, you can test with `iter(param)` alone

```
def flexible_func(param):
    try:
        iterable = iter(param)
    except TypeError:
        iterable = [param]
    for x in iterable:
        do_something(x)
```

A decorator version

```
def mystery(func):
    def inner(arg):
        try:
            return func(iter(arg))
        except TypeError:
            return func([arg])
    return inner

@mystery
def flexible_func(param):
    for x in param:
        do_something(x)
```

Comment: + its a trick, but is it preferable to write code like this?? can we check type of argument and run conditional code in Python.

Comment: I'd prefer to see a solution for `mystery_wrapper` rather than `flexible_func`, it will be more reusable.

Comment: @MarkRansom, Would a `mystery_wrapper` decorator be ok?

Comment: I've never completely wrapped my head around decorators, but they're totally Pythonic so go for it if you can.

Comment: You're better off checking hasattr(__iter__) than calling iter. Strings do not have an __iter__ method, but do return an interator (using __getitem__) if you call iter() on them.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
def wrapper(arg):
        try:
            for ar in arg:
                yield ar
        except:
            yield arg
```

and then use it as

```
for x in wrapper(range(1,5)):
    print x
```

or

```
for x in wrapper(1):
    print x
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I was hoping something like this was already built in though, perhaps in `itertools`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
import collections

def flexible_func(*param):
    li=[]
    for x in param:
        if isinstance(x,collections.Iterable):
            for y in x:
                li.append(y)
        else:
            li.append(x)
    do_something(li)

def do_something(li):
    for x in li:
        print x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flexible_func('single')
    flexible_func(['one', 'two'])
    flexible_func(range(6))
```